# Dapper GridReader already Disposed Error

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, dapper

I'm using Dapper dot net to execute a stored procedure that returns 4 result sets. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
    public Results Search(Query query)
    {
        if (query == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("query");

        Results results;
        var q = _sqlConnection.QueryMultiple("MySchema.MySproc", query,
                                             commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        {
            results = q.Read<Results>().First();
            results.CheckAlertResults = q.Read<Results.CheckAlertResult>().ToArray(); // Cannot access a disposed object.Object name: 'GridReader'.
            results.PersonAlertResultRows = q.Read<Results.PersonAlertResultRow>().ToArray();
            results.RoutingAlertResults = q.Read<Results.RoutingAlertResult>().ToArray();
        }

        return results;
    }
```

The first result set will only contain 1 row. It corresponds to a couple of primitive properties on my `Results` class.

The other 3 result sets will have many rows and will populate 3 complex array properties on the `Results` class.

For some reason, I'm getting

> Cannot access a disposed object.Object name: 'GridReader'.

Check my code to see where.

I have verified that the procedure is working correctly when called from LinqPad, which uses Linq2Sql.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure, your resultset is filled correctly? This exception happens if one of the results is empty. Because your dapper code looks fine to me.

Comment: @Alex no, it doesn't happen because of empty grids; empty grids are fine (see my answer)

Comment: @MarcGravell Ah sorry, I checked it just as you when less grids were returned as expected. Should have rephrased my comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reader will dispose itself when it fails to find any more results grids; basically, your C# code looks fine, but the suggestion is that your proc is only returning 1 grid. The following works fine, for example:

```
using (var reader = connection.QueryMultiple(
    "select 1; select 2 where 1 = 0; select 3 where 1 = 0; select 4;"))
{
    var one = reader.Read<int>().ToArray();
    var two = reader.Read<int>().ToArray();
    var three = reader.Read<int>().ToArray();
    var four = reader.Read<int>().ToArray();
    try { // only returned four grids; expect a fifth read to fail
        reader.Read<int>();
        throw new InvalidOperationException("this should not have worked!");
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException) {/* expected; success */}

    one.Length.IsEqualTo(1);
    one[0].IsEqualTo(1);
    two.Length.IsEqualTo(0);
    three.Length.IsEqualTo(0);
    four.Length.IsEqualTo(1);
    four[0].IsEqualTo(4);
}
```

I might try to improve the error message, but I *suspect* the error is in your SP.

Comment: Thanks for verifying that my client side code looks correct. This is my first time using Dapper's QueryMultiple, so I wasn't sure if I was doing something wrong. I'll open SQL profiler and see what I can see.

Comment: @Ronnie for the purposes of debugging, maybe just call it via ADO.NET `ExecuteReader`, and see how many grids there are (i.e. how many times can you call `NextResult()`, plus one)

Comment: The issue was with my stored procedure returning an error result set instead of raising an error. Thanks again.

Comment: I just ran into this today.  The issue was exactly as you described.  Thanks!